# ExtJS 6 Width based on aspect ratio for uploaded image

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an image (logo) on toolbar (application menu). I need image height to be fixed and width to be based on aspect ratio so I specify only height, like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'box',
    autoEl: {
        tag: 'img',
        src: 'http://placehold.it/200x100'
    },
    height: 50
}
```

The problem is when image downloaded (including disk cache) width is calculated as zero (when image instantly loaded from memory cache everything is ok).

Is there any workaround for this issue?

*I understand that as long as the image is not loaded I do not know its aspect ratio and can not correctly calculate the width. I can asynchronously load logo and explicitly set image source, but it looks like a bad solution.*

Here is simple [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2fcq) to illustrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`updateLayout()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.toolbar.Toolbar.html#method-updateLayout) method.

> **updateLayout**

Updates this component's layout. If this update affects this components [`ownerCt`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.toolbar.Toolbar.html#property-ownerCt), that component's `updateLayout` method will be called to perform the layout instead. Otherwise, just this component (and its child items) will layout.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2fd8)**, I have create a demo using your code and make modification with `updateLayout()` method. I hope this will help/guide you achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
            items: [{
                xtype: 'box',
                autoEl: {
                    tag: 'img',
                    src: 'http://placehold.it/200x100',
                    height: 50
                },
                listeners: {
                    afterrender: function (cmp) {
                        cmp.el.on('load', function (e) {
                            console.log('width', e.target.width, 'height', e.target.height);
                            cmp.up('toolbar').updateLayout()
                        }, cmp)
                    }
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Button'
            }],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```